# Gamemaker and undetected collisions

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'm making an RPG in Game Maker Studio Pro 1.4.1772, and I have a guy that can run around a demo room, and movement and collisions are all groovy.

I just tried to make a door to move to a new room. I've followed [this example](https://youtu.be/2ux8VFqj_jk) exactly, and have some weird issues. I don't think the issue is with my code (it obviously works - it's identical to the tutorial) so the problem is something else.

When my player character runs over the obj_door on the map, nothing happens. I've put debug messages into the collision event, and nothing. Nada. I've put a debug message into the creation code of the door:

```
show_debug_message("I exist:" + string(self));
```

And the string that prints is:

```
I exist:-1
```

Which I find odd.

So I edited my movement code that checks for collisions with obj_solid, and added the door collision code there:

```
if (place_meeting (x, y, obj_door)){ ...
```

Now, when I run into the door on the map, I get an error:

```
 FATAL ERROR in
 action number 1
 of  Step Event0
 for object obj_player:

 Variable <unknown_object>.<unknown variable>(100022, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Script_scr_player_move (line 75) -     player_x = other.target_x;
```

So when the object create code runs, it gives the object an id of -1, though I guess it's still actually running the create code? No collision is detected through the build-in collision event, but when I force the game to check for a collision with this object (that I'm not really sure even exists), it throws an  error. Why is this happening, and what else can I try in order to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` *is* `-1` - it's a special value. For instance ID, you might want `id`.

It is hard to guess without seeing more code, but `place_meeting` won't automatically store the colliding object in `other` - you might want to use `instance_place` like

```
var door = instance_place(x, y, obj_door);
if (door != noone) {
    player_x = other.target_x; // assuming that door has a target_x variable
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Do you have any idea why the regular collisions do not work here though? I've added the collision events with a code block that either shows a debug message, or tries the room change code as per that tutorial, but these pieces of code don't get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

other is reserved for usage in either **collision event** or **while** cycle. You are missusing it in the step event (log you posted says that clearly)